# Show all tabs in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way of showing all source code tabs in Android Studio one one horizontal line (in the tab bar) and scroll through them?

When there are too many source code tabs open in Android Studio, some of them are moved to the drop down list at the top right corner of the code edit window. The tabs that are moved to this drop down list are not shown in the tab bar any more.

The tabs in the tab bar can be scrolled with the mouse wheel, but only the ones that have not been moved to the drop down list.

Is there a way to remove the drop down list and keep all tabs in the tab bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of the tab bar is fixed and there are only fixed number of tabs that can fit inside that limited area.So, one way to quickly switch between the open tabs is to use the SWITCHER tool of Android Studio.

Press **control + tab** in MAC (don't know the shortcut for windows) and it will bring all the classes and other files which are currently open and you can efficiently switch between them without even touching your mouse or touchpad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Something weird just happened. I tried out the Switcher Tool but it's not quite what I want. But after trying it out, the tab bar actually worked the way I wanted it to. My guess is that it was a bug that somehow got bypassed when I tried the Switcher Tool.

Anyway, now the tab bar works the way I want it. Even though the tabs are not all shown at the same time, all the tabs are reachable by scrolling the tab bar (which wasn't the case before).

Answer (score 40):

Not sure if this feature was introduced in later versions of studio (than at the time of which this question was asked) but now you have option to show tabs in multiple rows. You can do so by

```
Windows -> Editor Tabs -> Tabs placement -> Show Tabs in single  row
```

You can uncheck above which is checked by default. Snapshot below -

[image]

Comment: Slight change in version 4; see gts's answer.

Answer (score 16):

In android Studio 4.0.1 you can find tabs configuration in:

Window->Editor Tabs->Configure Editor Tabs...

After, uncheck "Show tabs in one row" checkbox if it is selected.

[image: Configure Editor Tabs option]
[image: Configure Editor Tabs window]

Answer (score 1):

[image: **For Linux -**]

For Linux you can do similar to MAC